# MATLAB R2014a permission denied problem

Tags: permissions, matlab

I have installed MATLAB R2014a on my PC. It was all ok during installation, but at the end when I try to launch the program without `sudo` permission, I have this error message:

[image]

If i try with `sudo` permission, the program starts well.

Comment: What likely happened is that you've installed Matlab for root user. Matlab student license only grants permissions to specific username. In other words, you've installed it improperly

Answer (score 1):

According to the first line it would like to write on your storage, and it didn't have permission. Likely it writes in the /etc directory and it has root owner that's why you need to run it with `sudo`.

Comment: I solved giving 777 permission to Matlab folder

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

1. Go into the MATLAB installation directory using terminal.
2. Change installation file type in the sense of permission and execution:

   ```
   sudo chmod +x install
   ```
3. Run installer:

   ```
   sudo ./install
   ```

Apparently the aforementioned method provides permission in the necessary steps.